# System.Drawing.Font: no concept of font weight?

Tags: .net, system.drawing

I just noticed that in .net that System.Drawing.Font seems to have no concept of font weight other than FontStyle of normal and bold. I don't have the fine control I had in win32. The WPF framework has font weights, but I'm not using that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create the font using Win32, then wrap it using Font.FromHfont.